# Make image adapt to background colour in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am working on an app that includes the user taking a picture, then editing it. However, I have noticed that when the buttons used for editing are displayed, they are often not very visible due to the image background. The buttons contain images that have their colour set by tintColor. I would like the buttons to be visible no matter what the colours of the image are. I have found a CSS filter that achieves this, but there is no React Native implementation of it. I have also found a library that can do this (react-native-color-matrix-image-filters), but I cannot use it because I am using a managed Expo project with Expo Go.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Expo SDK 42, you can install a native library with Expo, you just need to compile a custom Expo Go client app with a native module (react-native-color-matrix-image-filters) pre-compiled and embedded.

You still have amazing Expo DX use native module support.

Check how to compile Expo Go Custom App here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id0Im72UN6w&t=25s

Comment: Thanks for your support, but I think that this method is a bit overkill for what im trying to do. I think that I will just continue using solid color buttons for now.

Comment: Yeah. I understand effort required to compile a custom client. Anyway, Take this into consideration when you want to add native module in future